# Jump/scroll to a section within Bulma modal card

Tags: bulma

I am trying to jump to a div on button click within bulma modal card, but when I am clicking on the button to jump to div, it is closing the modal.
Jquery on button click

```
    $('#scroll_bottom').click(function() {
       $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: ($('#bottom').first().offset().top)},500);
     });
```

How can jump/scroll to a div within bulma modal card

Comment: We may need to see more of your JS. I think your code for closing the modal is affecting this. Bulma modals do not close without additional code. You may need to either stop the scroll button click event from bubbling or modify the close code.